# Is it appropriate to change the title of a question with an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, title

I am curious if changing the title of a question is a good idea if the question has already been answered and had that answer accepted. I've read [Changing the title of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152252/201013) as well as the answer describing naming of a question in [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18616/201013), but I couldn't tell if this is a good thing to apply to every single question title that could be considered inaccurate.

For answered questions and very old questions, I wasn't sure whether it would even be important/worth bumping random questions to the top of the list and making them look like sorta-new questions from the title.

I'm not worried about closed questions as I assume all edits that improve the post (title included) are welcome.

Should I worry at all or make sure *every* title I see is accurate, even if it's late?

Comment: If the title is vague before, well then yes

Comment: An example might help discussion here, what do you mean by an "inaccurate" title?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15205280/1751715 - A question of my own, @blahdiblah. This is what sparked it, but I figured I could apply this to other titles as well. In this case the title is just overly vague. Obviously it's not working, else I wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Editing the title can and should be done, ***if*** appropriate.

There are two reasons for this:

- [Organic SEO](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/organic_seo.html), if the question title says `foo bar baz` but really solves `bat mat hat`. Then changing the title helps people to find the answer they are looking for.
- Ultimately the goal of Stack Exchange is to make the Internet better, and a big part of that is community editing. If you *know* you can improve the post and help future users by editing the title then do it.

Don't worry that your bumping a post back to the top. Stack Overflow gets so many questions a day and has so many filtering techniques that it will quickly fade away again, ***except*** for those that need it. Which is really the point anyway.

Comment: Just to add to Ryan's answer: Questions with bad titles are are a terrible problem for Google searchers.  I'm searching for *"Setting up Foo with Bar,"* and I wind up at some Stack Overflower's post about some highly-obscure error message he is getting while fooing the bar.  Very frustrating.  The more that can be done about these kinds of titles, the better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I hate when I'm *setting up foo to work with bar* and all google says is *bar caused an error in foo*. Why can't bar have a wiki for setup and play nice with foo? '*sigh*'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be stated enough, and I'm sure titling is getting slowly worse.

I've always edited titles where I know there are one or more:

- Grammatical errors (usually, but not always confined to non-native English speakers)
- Spelling errors
- Poor meaning/context
- Word shortening
- [Leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)

And regardless of prior acceptance, it's important to convey accuracy as many people make subconscious assumptions about titles - knowing what they mean.

It's largely as [ryan states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175896/is-it-appropriate-to-change-the-title-of-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer/175897#175897) - [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) is a big deal for searchers and knowing that better context and titling will make finding answers much easier.