# modify incorrect title based on answers

Tags: support, title

If you ask a question with the *incorrect notion* that the problem is '**x**', which you express in the title of the question,

then, you receive an answer which points out that the problem has nothing to do with 'x' - but rather **'y**'...

Are you supposed to then modify your question to reflect the real problem?

For example my question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658482/media-queries-glitch-in-ie/16716948?noredirect=1#16716948)** supposes that the problem the IE is because of media queries, when in fact it is because of the way that IE handles sub-pixels - would I modify the title to reflect this?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thanks for the link. However, firstly, there are no answers there and secondly, there- the questioner is asking if he - as  a *user* [as opposed to the questioner himself] should edit the title, whereas i'm asking if the questioner himself should edit title. Should I edit the title here to make that clearer ;) ?

Comment: I think I pasted the wrong duplicate, sorry! I found one that had at least one answer. As for question owner/others, I don't think there's a difference. That's the point of "everyone can edit" -- anyone who notices something that could be better can and should make it so.

Comment: How about this one? [Changing the title of a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152252/changing-the-title-of-a-post)

Comment: hmmm I just read that question and answer, and i'm still not sure what  I should do in my case

Comment: @JoshCaswell and other users etc: FYI the answer in the 'duplicate' question didn't help me, but hamar's answer did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better if you avoid speculating about the cause of the problem in the title, whether you are correct or not. Focus on what you *know*.

For example, in your question you know that `calc()` is giving you the wrong margins in IE for some reason. That's what your title should be about.

Comment: +1 that's what I was thinking as well

Answer (score 2):

Maybe.

In cases where the original question was way off the mark and focus was established only through comment-based discussion, an update might be helpful. Since comments are not considered permanent, it is helpful to ensure that the question contains all of the necessary information.

However, if the incorrect focus was pointed out in an answer, the change might cause confusion in the future because the answers were geared toward the original question, not the edited one. Additionally, other users might be using the same bad assumptions as the OP did and will benefit by following the same path.